# Difference between "key in dict" and "dict.get(key)" on key check

Tags: python

When I was doing [Leetcode 820](https://leetcode-cn.com/problems/short-encoding-of-words/), building a Trie, there is a bug in my code. I found it, also corrected it, but did NOT understand why. Could anyone help?

I made a simple test code here. Program 1 and Program 2 are doing same thing, that is, given a word list `words`, it builds a Trie in reversed order of these words. Variable `trie` stored the root of Trie, variable `leaves` stored beginning character of each word. The only difference between program 1 and program 2 is in line `# difference`, and I focus on the different results of `leaves` in 2 programs.

```
words = ["time", "atime", "btime"]

# program 1
trie = dict()
leaves = []
for word in words:
    node = trie
    for c in reversed(word):
        if c not in node:  # difference
            node[c] = dict()
        node = node[c]
    leaves.append(node)
print("from program 1: ")
print(leaves)

# program 2
trie = dict()
leaves = []
for word in words:
    node = trie
    for c in reversed(word):
        if not node.get(c):  # difference
            node[c] = dict()
        node = node[c]
    leaves.append(node)
print("from program 2: ")
print(leaves)
```

However the outputs of `leaves` are totally different.

```
from program 1: 
[{'a': {}, 'b': {}}, {}, {}]
from program 2: 
[{}, {}, {}]
```

Could anyone help explain why results of `leaves` in program 1 and program 2 are different? Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: The difference is that `node.get(c)` is falsy if `c not in node` *or* if `node[c]` is empty.

Comment: For one, `c not in node` is only `True` if `c` is not in `node`, i.e. if there is no key `c` in dictionary `node` in this case. However, `not node.get(c)` would also be `True` if the 'truthy' value of `node.get(c)` would be `False`, for example when `node[c]` is `0`, `''`, `False`, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`c not in node` can only be True when `node` does not contain the key `c`.

Lots of things can make `not node.get(c)` return True. Any falsy value, for example, like an empty `list`, `dict` or `str`, or something like `0` or `0.0`, evaluates to boolean False, just like `None` does. So you are liable to get a false negative any time `node` contains `c`, but has a falsy value.

If you're absolutely sure that your mapping can not contain None values, you can do the following:

```
if node.get(c) is not None:
```

If course explicitly checking for a key is always better than implicitly checking is by other means because of unintended side-effects like that.

Comment: Thanks my friend, you proposed a great point that I never realized before. However,  in my case, I still don't understand why `leaves` would have different behaviors in 2 programs?

Comment: @Tony陈. You should trace through your code in a debugger. But here's a hint: you initialize `node[c] = dict()`. What happens when you run `if not node.get(c)` on it? Instead of nesting your dictionaries you are placing everything in the top level.

Comment: Great, bro, you are exactly right. I'm so grateful to your help!

Answer (score 2):

One obvious difference:

- `key in dict` will only give you a false value if the key is not there.
- `dict.get(key)` will give you the actual value for that key which is then treated as a truthy or falsey value. So, if the value for an existing key is falsey (such as zero or the empty string), the `if` statement will not fire (though it will in the previous bullet point).

The following example shows this:

```py
>>> d = {1: 0, 2: 42}

>>> 1 in d
True

>>> if d.get(1): print("yes")
...

>>> 2 in d
True

>>> if d.get(2): print("yes")
...
yes
```

---

If, as it seems, you're just trying to establish whether a key exists, the `key in dict` method is the correct way to go (you don't really *care* what the value is, just whether the value exists).

Comment: Thanks my friend, this point is so valuable to me. However, in my case, I still don't understand why `leaves` would have different results in 2 programs?